# Tri-fold brochure - Not able to produce content in all pages

Tags: formatting

I am making a trifold brochure type info sheet. The sheet is to be printed on either side and then cut into three separate pieces for distributing.
But I am not able to generate any content on one of the brochure pages.

Thank you

```
\documentclass[notumble,twopart,11pt,a4paper]{leaflet}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{flowfram}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{caption} 
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.0}
%\titleformat*{\subsection}{\color{Blue}}

\newcommand{\sectionline}{
    \nointerlineskip \vspace{\baselineskip}
    \hspace{\fill}\rule{0.8\linewidth}{.7pt}\hspace{\fill}
    \par\nointerlineskip \vspace{\baselineskip}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{minipage}{0.98\textwidth}

        \centering
        \small{\textbf{Department of Electronics \\\& \\Communication Engineering}\\
            %\vspace*{10pt}
            {\footnotesize \textbf{{College of Engineering Trivandrum}}}}\\
        {\footnotesize\textbf{{Outcome Based Education (OBE)}}}\\
        {\small \textbf{B.Tech. \\Applied Electronics \& Instrumentation Engg.}}\\

        \framebox{
            \begin{minipage}[t]{.98\linewidth}
                %                \begin{center}
                %                   \textbf{\small{Department Vision}}
                %                \end{center}
                \centering \textbf{\small{Department Vision}}
                \justify{\small{To transform young students into responsible and competent professionals with focus on dissemination of knowledge in the sphere of Electronics, Communication and Instrumentation Engineering}}
        \end{minipage}}

        \centering \textbf{\newline \small{Department Mission}}
        \setlist{nolistsep}
        \begin{itemize}[noitemsep]
            \small{
                \item To impart Quality Engineering education to satisfy the needs of academics, industry and society.
                \item To achieve excellence in teaching-learning, research and innovation in the area of Electronics, Communication and Instrumentation Engineering.
                \item To facilitate networking with alumni,industries and institutions in bringing about excellence and nourishing the entrepreneurial skills of the students.
                \item To practice highest level of professional integrity, transparency and accountability.}
        \end{itemize}

        \justify \small{\textbf{OBE} is student-centered instruction model that focuses on measuring student performance through \textbf{outcomes}. A \textbf{learning outcome} is what a student can do as a result of a learning experience (for example on completion of course/lecture/assignment/tutorial or upon graduation.}\\ 
        \begin{tcolorbox}
            \begin{center}
                \small{\textbf{OBE Components}\\
                    Department Vision \& Mission\\
                    Program Educational Objectives (PEO's 1- 4)\\
                    Program Specific Outcomes (PSO's 1- 3)\\
                    Program Outcomes (PO's 1-12)\\
                    Course Outcomes (CO's)}
            \end{center}
        \end{tcolorbox}
        \justify \scriptsize \textbf{The 12 PO's} - If you \textbf{know} the \textbf{problem}, attempt to analyze n \textbf{solve}; \textbf{investigate} \textbf{using modern tools}.The \textbf{society} needs \textbf{sustainable} and \textbf{ethical} solutions developed by \textbf{team work} that \textbf{communicates},\textbf{manages project} \& \textbf{life}\\
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}{0.98\textwidth}

        \centering
            \small{\textbf{Department of Electronics \\\& \\Communication Engineering}\\
            %\vspace*{10pt}
            {\footnotesize \textbf{{College of Engineering Trivandrum}}}}\\
            {\footnotesize\textbf{{Outcome Based Education (OBE)}}}\\
            {\small \textbf{B.Tech. \\Applied Electronics \& Instrumentation Engg.}}\\

             \framebox{
                \begin{minipage}[t]{.98\linewidth}
%                \begin{center}
%                   \textbf{\small{Department Vision}}
%                \end{center}
            \centering \textbf{\small{Department Vision}}
             \justify{\small{To transform young students into responsible and competent professionals with focus on dissemination of knowledge in the sphere of Electronics, Communication and Instrumentation Engineering}}
                \end{minipage}}

            \centering \textbf{\newline \small{Department Mission}}
            \setlist{nolistsep}
            \begin{itemize}[noitemsep]
            \small{
            \item To impart Quality Engineering education to satisfy the needs of academics, industry and society.
            \item To achieve excellence in teaching-learning, research and innovation in the area of Electronics, Communication and Instrumentation Engineering.
            \item To facilitate networking with alumni,industries and institutions in bringing about excellence and nourishing the entrepreneurial skills of the students.
            \item To practice highest level of professional integrity, transparency and accountability.}
            \end{itemize}

        \justify \small{\textbf{OBE} is student-centered instruction model that focuses on measuring student performance through \textbf{outcomes}. A \textbf{learning outcome} is what a student can do as a result of a learning experience (for example on completion of course/lecture/assignment/tutorial or upon graduation.}\\ 
        \begin{tcolorbox}
            \begin{center}
                \small{\textbf{OBE Components}\\
                    Department Vision \& Mission\\
                    Program Educational Objectives (PEO's 1- 4)\\
                    Program Specific Outcomes (PSO's 1- 3)\\
                    Program Outcomes (PO's 1-12)\\
                    Course Outcomes (CO's)}
            \end{center}
         \end{tcolorbox}
     \justify \scriptsize \textbf{The 12 PO's} - If you \textbf{know} the \textbf{problem}, attempt to analyze n \textbf{solve}; \textbf{investigate} \textbf{using modern tools}.The \textbf{society} needs \textbf{sustainable} and \textbf{ethical} solutions developed by \textbf{team work} that \textbf{communicates},\textbf{manages project} \& \textbf{life}\\
        \end{minipage}
    \thispagestyle{empty} 
    \newpage
    \begin{tcolorbox}
        \justify
            \small{\textbf{Program Educational Objectives - PEO's}\\
                 PEO 1 - Graduates will have successful professional career in industry and academic institutions as engineers, managers and academicians.\\
                PEO 2 - Graduates will be successful in providing solutions to engineering problems through innovation and research in the field of Electronics and Instrumentation Engineering.\\
                PEO 3 - Graduates will advance in their career through higher education and pursue research for the betterment of society.\\
                PEO 4 - Graduates follow good ethical practices, right professional conduct and provide responsible team leadership.
            }
    \end{tcolorbox}

    \begin{tcolorbox}
        \begin{center}
            \small{\textbf{Program Specific Outcomes - PSO's}\\
                PSO 1 - Domain Knowledge\\
                PSO 2 - Application Skill\\
                PSO 3 - Research\\
                }
        \end{center}
    \end{tcolorbox}
    \begin{tcolorbox}

            \small{\textbf{Program Outcomes - PO}\\
                PO 1 - Engineering Knowledge\\
                PO 2 - Problem Analysis\\
                PO 3 - Design \& Development of solutions\\
                PO 4 - Conduct investigations of complex problems\\
                PO 5 - Modern tool usage\\
                PO 6 - The Engineer \& Society\\
                PO 7 - Environment \& Sustainability\\
                PO 8 - Ethics\\
                PO 9 - Individual \& Teamwork\\
                PO 10- Communication\\
                PO 11- Project management \& finance\\
                PO 12- Life long learning\\
                }
    \end{tcolorbox}

     \small \textbf{Criteria}\hspace{15pt} \small\textbf{When it is evaluated}\\
     \small CO\hspace{40pt}\small Upon course completion\\
     \small PO\hspace{40pt}\small Upon graduation\\
    \small PEO\hspace{35pt}\small 4-5 years after graduation\\
   %\end{minipage}

        \newpage
        \begin{minipage}{0.98\textwidth}

            \centering
            \small{\textbf{Department of Electronics \\\& \\Communication Engineering}\\
                %\vspace*{10pt}
                {\footnotesize \textbf{{College of Engineering Trivandrum}}}}\\
            {\footnotesize\textbf{{Outcome Based Education (OBE)}}}\\
            {\small \textbf{B.Tech. \\Applied Electronics \& Instrumentation Engg.}}\\

            \framebox{
                \begin{minipage}[t]{.98\linewidth}
                    %                \begin{center}
                    %                   \textbf{\small{Department Vision}}
                    %                \end{center}
                    \centering \textbf{\small{Department Vision}}
                    \justify{\small{To transform young students into responsible and competent professionals with focus on dissemination of knowledge in the sphere of Electronics, Communication and Instrumentation Engineering}}
            \end{minipage}}

            \centering \textbf{\newline \small{Department Mission}}
            \setlist{nolistsep}
            \begin{itemize}[noitemsep]
                \small{
                    \item To impart Quality Engineering education to satisfy the needs of academics, industry and society.
                    \item To achieve excellence in teaching-learning, research and innovation in the area of Electronics, Communication and Instrumentation Engineering.
                    \item To facilitate networking with alumni,industries and institutions in bringing about excellence and nourishing the entrepreneurial skills of the students.
                    \item To practice highest level of professional integrity, transparency and accountability.}
            \end{itemize}

            \justify \small{\textbf{OBE} is student-centered instruction model that focuses on measuring student performance through \textbf{outcomes}. A \textbf{learning outcome} is what a student can do as a result of a learning experience (for example on completion of course/lecture/assignment/tutorial or upon graduation.}\\ 
            \begin{tcolorbox}
                \begin{center}
                    \small{\textbf{OBE Components}\\
                        Department Vision \& Mission\\
                        Program Educational Objectives (PEO's 1- 4)\\
                        Program Specific Outcomes (PSO's 1- 3)\\
                        Program Outcomes (PO's 1-12)\\
                        Course Outcomes (CO's)}
                \end{center}
            \end{tcolorbox}
            \justify \scriptsize \textbf{The 12 PO's} - If you \textbf{know} the \textbf{problem}, attempt to analyze n \textbf{solve}; \textbf{investigate} \textbf{using modern tools}.The \textbf{society} needs \textbf{sustainable} and \textbf{ethical} solutions developed by \textbf{team work} that \textbf{communicates},\textbf{manages project} \& \textbf{life}\\
        \end{minipage}
        \thispagestyle{empty} 
        \newpage



        \begin{tcolorbox}
            \justify
            \small{\textbf{Program Educational Objectives - PEO's}\\
                PEO 1 - Graduates will have successful professional career in industry and academic institutions as engineers, managers and academicians.\\
                PEO 2 - Graduates will be successful in providing solutions to engineering problems through innovation and research in the field of Electronics and Instrumentation Engineering.\\
                PEO 3 - Graduates will advance in their career through higher education and pursue research for the betterment of society.\\
                PEO 4 - Graduates follow good ethical practices, right professional conduct and provide responsible team leadership.
            }
        \end{tcolorbox}

        \begin{tcolorbox}
            \begin{center}
                \small{\textbf{Program Specific Outcomes - PSO's}\\
                    PSO 1 - Domain Knowledge\\
                    PSO 2 - Application Skill\\
                    PSO 3 - Research\\
                }
            \end{center}
        \end{tcolorbox}
        \begin{tcolorbox}

            \small{\textbf{Program Outcomes - PO}\\
                PO 1 - Engineering Knowledge\\
                PO 2 - Problem Analysis\\
                PO 3 - Design \& Development of solutions\\
                PO 4 - Conduct investigations of complex problems\\
                PO 5 - Modern tool usage\\
                PO 6 - The Engineer \& Society\\
                PO 7 - Environment \& Sustainability\\
                PO 8 - Ethics\\
                PO 9 - Individual \& Teamwork\\
                PO 10- Communication\\
                PO 11- Project management \& finance\\
                PO 12- Life long learning\\
            }
        \end{tcolorbox}

        \small \textbf{Criteria}\hspace{15pt} \small\textbf{When it is evaluated}\\
        \small CO\hspace{40pt}\small Upon course completion\\
        \small PO\hspace{40pt}\small Upon graduation\\
        \small PEO\hspace{35pt}\small 4-5 years after graduation\\
        %\end{minipage}
    \thispagestyle{empty} 
    \newpage
    \begin{tcolorbox}
        \justify
        \small{\textbf{Program Educational Objectives - PEO's}\\
            PEO 1 - Graduates will have successful professional career in industry and academic institutions as engineers, managers and academicians.\\
            PEO 2 - Graduates will be successful in providing solutions to engineering problems through innovation and research in the field of Electronics and Instrumentation Engineering.\\
            PEO 3 - Graduates will advance in their career through higher education and pursue research for the betterment of society.\\
            PEO 4 - Graduates follow good ethical practices, right professional conduct and provide responsible team leadership.
        }
    \end{tcolorbox}

    \begin{tcolorbox}
        \begin{center}
            \small{\textbf{Program Specific Outcomes - PSO's}\\
                PSO 1 - Domain Knowledge\\
                PSO 2 - Application Skill\\
                PSO 3 - Research\\
            }
        \end{center}
    \end{tcolorbox}
    \begin{tcolorbox}

        \small{\textbf{Program Outcomes - PO}\\
            PO 1 - Engineering Knowledge\\
            PO 2 - Problem Analysis\\
            PO 3 - Design \& Development of solutions\\
            PO 4 - Conduct investigations of complex problems\\
            PO 5 - Modern tool usage\\
            PO 6 - The Engineer \& Society\\
            PO 7 - Environment \& Sustainability\\
            PO 8 - Ethics\\
            PO 9 - Individual \& Teamwork\\
            PO 10- Communication\\
            PO 11- Project management \& finance\\
            PO 12- Life long learning\\
        }
    \end{tcolorbox}

    \small \textbf{Criteria}\hspace{15pt} \small\textbf{When it is evaluated}\\
    \small CO\hspace{40pt}\small Upon course completion\\
    \small PO\hspace{40pt}\small Upon graduation\\
    \small PEO\hspace{35pt}\small 4-5 years after graduation\\
    %\end{minipage}    

\end{document}
```

Comment: Most of your packages are not being used.  Some are loaded twice.  You are loading both color and xcolor, and apparently xcolor and setspace are incompatible.  (My advice is to lose setspace.)

Comment: Your first minipage is larger than \textheight (569.35571pt vs. 534.91183pt).

Comment: Why do you think `xcolor` and `setspace` aren't compatible @JohnKormylo?

Comment: Hello all,
Thanks for the pointers. This is what I did and got it solved.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I tested before commenting and didn't even get a warning.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I also have at least one custom class which uses both, I realise. It would be odd if they were incompatible, because `setspace` really doesn't do much, as you know.

Comment: @cfr - When I ran the MWE again, no error message.  Never mind.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the pointers. This is what I did and got it solved by trimming the packages and this is the result:

```latex
\documentclass[notumble,twopart,11pt,a4paper]{leaflet}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{caption} 
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.0}
```